# Can I have a single submit button that performs two actions?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

here is the code of form:

```
<?php
include("updater.php");
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
increment(); //increments value of question no.(I don't want to use auto_increment   hence this)
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add Questions</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="get_question.php" method="post">
<?php $q_no=$counter;
       echo "Q.no.".$q_no  ?><br/>
Question:<input type="text" name="question" cols="40" rows="3" /> <br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c1"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2"/>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c2"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c3"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c4"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next Question>>">
</form>
</form>
```

***Updater.php:***

```
<?php
 $connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    if(!$connection){
        die("could not connect to database".mysql_error());
    }

 $select_db=mysql_select_db("oes",$connection);
    if(!$select_db){
        die("could not select database".mysql_error());
    }

$result=mysql_query("SELECT q_no FROM counter WHERE ptr='here'");
$row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
$counter= $row["q_no"];

     function increment(){
        global $counter;
        $counter++;
        $updated=mysql_query("UPDATE  oes.counter SET  q_no =  '$counter' WHERE  counter.ptr ='here';");
        return $counter;
    }

     function delete($q_no){
        $action_delete1=mysql_query("DELETE FROM oes.questions WHERE q_no='$q_no';");
        $action_delete2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM oes.choices WHERE q_no='$q_no';"); 
        $action_adddeleted=mysql_query("INSERT INTO oes.deleted (q_no) VALUES ('$q_no');");
    }

    function use_delete(){
        $retrive=mysql_query("SELECT MAX (q_no) AS q_no FROM deleted");
        $action_delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM oes.deleted WHERE q_no='$retrive';");
        return $retrive;
    }

?>
```

The problem is that submit button just updates question in database but gives same page with same q_no and then by pressing next question button i have to go to next one(increment()) is there a way to do two tasks on same button click?

Comment: maybe you can use a `div` instead of `<input type="submit" .../>` and on div to have a function attached to onclick event and on that function you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="get_question.php" method="post">
<?php $q_no=$counter;
       echo "Q.no.".$q_no  ?><br/>
Question:<input type="text" name="question" cols="40" rows="3" /> <br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c1"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2"/>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c2"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c3"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c4"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next Question>>">
</form>
```

Remove that nested form. Then you have to ensure the processing for answering a question triggers the next question code. Effectively doing what you seem to be asking for without actually having 2 separate actions.

Comment: if i just use submit button then on every reload of page(even F5) the question no automatically increments.

Comment: Cause you don't tell it to. We have to see the logic of your form processor to suggest how you might achieve this.

Comment: For one you're running the fetch code before increment. You should run all form processing BEFORE anything that will output to the page. I also don't see anything that's reading the post values, so you're just ignoring the answer and moving to the next question. I assume 'here' is a placeholder that may someday represent a user.

Comment: that code is in another php file it has nothng to do it just takes data and puts it in appropriate databases and here points to value of question no

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform two separate HTTP requests with a single form submission so the answer to your question is no, it can't perform two actions.

You could use JavaScript to issue to separate HTTP requests instead (ajax), or you could simply have your PHP back end perform the two actions that you need.  There is nothing stopping it from incrementing *and* redirecting to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data from database then,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// get your current question no. : $next_no = SELECT q_no from table WHERE q_no=$current_question_no;
// fetch next question: SELECT * FROM table where q_no=($next_no+1);
//here will be some SQL query to increment..
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden input in the form that tracks the value of q_no.

```
<input type="hidden" name="qcount" value=$q_no /> (or similar, I don't use php much)
```

Comment: `value="<?php echo $q_no; ?>"`